# Refresh another IFRAME Window

Tags: html, target

I have this line that works when I click the word Test:

```
<a href="SearchThis.php" target="SearchThisFrame">Test</a>
```

How can I re-code this so I do not have to click the word Test or select anything, just have it execute?

This should be simple, just starring at it to long.......

Update: This sort of works. It will open SearchThis.php but not in the target window, only the window it was executed from. This is inside php and the last line. I am close to a solution.....

```
header("Location:\\SerchThis.php target=SearchThisFrame");
```

Thanks to Gerben we have a solution. I cant tell you how many post and how many searches I did for this solution, nothing worked except this one. I have added code to include passing a php generated variable. I placed this script at the very end, past the last ?> and before the /body tag in order to pick up the varable.

```
<script>
window.open('SearchThis.php?passthis=<?php echo "Variable"; ?>', 'SearchThisFrame');
</script>
```

Comment: When do you want it to execute? At page load? (it will only run once)

Comment: I have it after some PHP code and would like to have it execute after the script runs. So a 2-3 second delay after page load would be perfect. And I only need it to run once.

Comment: This sort of works. It will load "SearchThis.ph" in the same window it was executed from and not the target..... Getting close.... See original post above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
window.open('SearchThis.php', 'SearchThisFrame');
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you Gerben works perfect....... I update my original post above to also include passing variables from PHP along with it.... Thanks again..